# Right-Angle Adapters and Plug for Air Conditioner Exhaust

Tags: air-conditioning, ventilation

[image: Full Picture of AC with exhaust tube]

**Full picture of AC with exhaust tube.**

[image: Exhaust port through window]

**Exhaust port through window.**

---

As shown, I have an air conditioner which has an exhaust hose which moves out hot air through the window and outside. I did a fairly good job weather-sealing it, and after some recent heavy rains, the weather-proofing has worked extremely well :)

I've been trying to look for a couple things, for which I have been unsuccessful.

First, it would be really nice to have a sort of "cap" or "plug" that I can use to close the port when the air conditioner tube is not connected. During the winter, I could attach the plug and move the air conditioner into the closet, freeing up some floor space.

Second, I've also been looking for a set of right-angle slim adapters to make it possible to put the air conditioner itself much closer to the wall. The hose currently doesn't turn enough to make this possible.

I've tried searching with a lot of different terms. Do right angle adapters and plugs/caps exist, and what are they called?

Comment: They are next to the left hand smoke deflectors.

Comment: Sorry could not resist but shopping advice is off topic. I might try a local plumbing and electrical store , they usually have adjustable 6” ductwork. The local guys will usually be more help at finding the parts you want or directing you to a sheet metal shop that can make exactly what you want.

Comment: https://www.lowes.com/pd/IMPERIAL-6-in-dia-Galvanized-Steel-Round-End-Cap/3711202

Answer (score 1):

Look for the periscope vents at your local home stores or online. This particular one's from Appliance Parts 365, which I have absolutely no ties to.
End caps are also available at home stores too, next to the left handed screwdrivers.

[image]

Comment: "Left handed screwdrivers" so you're saying that caps don't exist.

Comment: @NaftuliKay  They do exist...  just joking with Ed....  stay safe out there .. happy new year